# To "sudo" or "not to sudo" or may just "pip3"?

Tags: 18.04, odoo

Trying to 'understand' the installation of odoo12 on Ubuntu 18.04 (Reasons ... moving up from odoo11/16.04, openupgrade 12-13 not quite their, 20.04 comes with python 3.8)

So many tutorials, so many pitfalls, they are all different, they all have issues.

To help me along, if someone could please advise...

Why would I....

```
sudo apt-get install python-pypdf2
```

while some dont?

why would I

```
sudo pip3 install pypdf2
```

while some just...

```
pip3 install pypdf2
```

One thing for sure, I must be building a "Swiss Cheese" secure Odoo install

Comment: One obvious thing to ask here is whether the version of `pypdf2` you get from `apt` is suitable for whatever you're going use it with

Comment: You don't want to do this at all, but instead make use of a `virtualenv` with a dedicated Odoo user with its own home directory. I can add detailed instructions in an answer if you require it.